# Project Euler Problem #87 - Prime power triples

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

I found this problem in Project Euler: https://projecteuler.net/problem=87

> The smallest number expressible as the sum of a prime square, prime
>   cube, and prime fourth power is $28$. In fact, there are exactly four
>   numbers $<50$ that can be expressed in such a way:
>
> $$28 = 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4$$
>    $$33 = 3^2 + 2^3 + 2^4$$
>    $$49 = 5^2 + 2^3 + 2^4$$
>    $$47 = 2^2 + 3^3 + 2^4$$
>
> How many numbers $<50\, 000\, 000$ can be expressed as the sum of a
>   prime square, prime cube, and prime fourth power?

What's the optimized solution to solve this problem?

Comment: You can just brute-force it with a program searching through combinations of primes up to $\lfloor\sqrt{50\, 000\, 000}\rfloor=7081$ for squares, up to $\lfloor\sqrt[3]{50\, 000\, 000}\rfloor=368$ for cubes, up to $\lfloor\sqrt[4]{50\, 000\, 000}\rfloor=84$ for fourth powers. You will only need 26 bits.

Comment: @user3491648 the the method given by user26486 will only require a 6 digit number of iterations. The computational complexity of just coming up with a list of primes is much greater than that of the iteration, even if you have to remove duplicates.

Comment: Not every number in the range will be prime, you will have roughly 800*60*20 = 960,000 iterations.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish Apologies. I've deleted my comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll need $\le \lceil \log_2(150\, 000\, 000)\rceil=28$ bits for the method. Not much of a difference of course. You can improve it though.

Comment: The limit should be small enough even for a brute-force program in PARI/GP

Comment: $64$ bits are handled without a problem on C++ using long long int. You can add libraries to use $128$ bits or more as well.

Comment: @user26486 can you please describe it more?